# How does return statement in dojo work?

Tags: javascript, parameters, dojo, return

I think i have a basic problem in understanding the dojo toolkit. Well I know in javascript returning a variable and calling it in another function works like this:

```
function a(){
  var x=5;
  return x;
}

function b(){
  var y=a();
  console.log(y);
}
```

> > 5

Well, now i need the imgsize in function b() and can show you my dojo code. I tried the whole afternoon to call imgsize in my function b() but I didnÄt get it... perhaps u can help me :)

```
require(["dojo/window"], function(win){
        // Get the viewport-size of the document:
        var viewportsize =win.getBox();
        var imgsize = (viewportsize.w)/4;
    });


function b(){
  var x = ???????
}
```

Comment: as it is asynchronous, you can't access imgsize before dojo/window is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a scope issue.  You defined the variable inside the function, so once the function is executed, imgsize is gone.

```
require(["dojo/window"], function(win){
    // Get the viewport-size of the document:
    var viewportsize =win.getBox();
    dojo.setObject('imageSize', (viewportsize.w)/4);
});


function b(){
  var x = dojo.getObject('imageSize');
}
```